# Adding service in init.rc in android 4.4.2

Tags: android, init

I am adding the following code in init.rc in android 4.4.2.

```
service test /system/bin/test
    class main
    user gps
    group gps radio inet system rpc
    socket test stream 0660 gps system
```

After boot up I checked the init.rc file in / the modified lines are present.
But still the service is not started when I check for ps command its not listed there.

Any one can tell me what could be the problem.

Comment: What is /system/bin/test and where did you get it?  Post the output of `ls -l /system/bin/test` also attempt to run it from the shell and report what happens.

Comment: /system/bin/test is a executable that will run as daemon at bootup time. It will act as a gps server which will serve any incoming gps position request from any gps application. I checked the output of   ls -l /system/bin/test it has the execute permission.  I am able to run it manually and it is showing in out put of ps command. One more thing I wanted to mentioned when I run it manually and chcek the output of ps command I see 2 instance of test in it.

Comment: Can you add some logging to it in order to know if it ever even starts?  Seems like you should be trying to figure out if it never starts, or if it starts but fails for some reason.  Does it depend on any libraries which might not be available yet?

Comment: Thanks Chris this problem is now resolved. I compile the complete android code and flash it after that I checked the ps the server was runing from bootup.